# how to hide button if value is 0 or empty?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a quiz app that bring question with multiple possible answer from database, i just have a problem hiding a button when i need to put like 2 possible answers not 3 or 4

here is the html code :

```
<button class="btn btn-default answer" type="submit" name="score" value="<?=$qdata["sc1"]?>" style="white-space: normal; font-size: 15px;"><?=base64_decode($qdata["an1"])?></button>
<button class="btn btn-default answer" type="submit" name="score" value="<?=$qdata["sc2"]?>" style="white-space: normal; font-size: 15px;"><?=base64_decode($qdata["an2"])?></button>
<button class="btn btn-default answer" type="submit" name="score" value="<?=$qdata["sc3"]?>" style="white-space: normal; font-size: 15px;"><?=base64_decode($qdata["an3"])?></button>
<button class="btn btn-default answer" type="submit" name="score" value="<?=$qdata["sc4"]?>" style="white-space: normal; font-size: 15px;"><?=base64_decode($qdata["an4"])?></button>
```

i don't know how to hide the button when the value is empty, sorry for my English.

Comment: `if(!empty($qdata["sc1"])) { /*show button*/ }`

Comment: Seems like you should hide it with php....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should be showing/hiding the buttons based on whether or not you get the data from the server, not after you already updated the button with the data. Regardless this is probably what you're asking for.

Edit: in your case, you also probably want to check to make sure `button.value != ''` since your data could be just blank.

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

buttons.forEach(function(button) {
  if (!button.value) {
    button.style.display = "none"
  }
});
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-default answer" type="submit" name="score" value="1" style="white-space: normal; font-size: 15px;">1</button>
<button class="btn btn-default answer" type="submit" name="score" value="2" style="white-space: normal; font-size: 15px;">2</button>
<button class="btn btn-default answer" type="submit" name="score" style="white-space: normal; font-size: 15px;">3</button>
<button class="btn btn-default answer" type="submit" name="score" value="4" style="white-space: normal; font-size: 15px;">4</button>
```

Comment: thank you sir. you got what i wanted to do, i'm just a beginner and didn't need to make it hard, but i didn't ask right because i didn't mean the value of sc but the value of an like an3 or an4, is it possible?

Comment: can you clarify what is `sc` and what is `an`? I don't know php so I might not be able to help in that area.

Comment: sc is the score of each answer which is integer , an refers to answer as text, the user just see the text not the score anyway the score of the answer is just for calculating, i just want the button to hide or remove when there is no third or fourth answer for the question

Comment: Ah, if you want to check the text inside the button use `button.textContent` instead of `button.value`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure CSS solution if javascript is not something you're looking for

```css
button[value=""],
button[value="0"]{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" value="">A</button>
<button type="submit" value="B">B</button>
<button type="submit" value="C">C</button>
<button type="submit" value="0">D</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let btns = document.querySelectorAll("button");

btns.forEach(function(par){
  if(par.value == "" || par.value == 0){
    par.style.display = "none";
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way by hide in html code:

```
<button class="btn btn-default answer" type="submit" name="score" value="<?=$qdata["sc1"]?>" style="white-space: normal; font-size: 15px;<?php echo $qdata["sc1"] ? "" : "display: none;" ?>"><?=base64_decode($qdata["an1"])?></button>
<button class="btn btn-default answer" type="submit" name="score" value="<?=$qdata["sc2"]?>" style="white-space: normal; font-size: 15px;<?php echo $qdata["sc2"] ? "" : "display: none;" ?>"><?=base64_decode($qdata["an2"])?></button>
<button class="btn btn-default answer" type="submit" name="score" value="<?=$qdata["sc3"]?>" style="white-space: normal; font-size: 15px;<?php echo $qdata["sc3"] ? "" : "display: none;" ?>"><?=base64_decode($qdata["an3"])?></button>
<button class="btn btn-default answer" type="submit" name="score" value="<?=$qdata["sc4"]?>" style="white-space: normal; font-size: 15px;<?php echo $qdata["sc4"] ? "" : "display: none;" ?>"><?=base64_decode($qdata["an4"])?></button>
```

Comment: thank you this works too, but sorry unfortunately i can't upvote yet since i'm new, but thanks sir.